# Mdiform resizing occurs form docking error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize, splitcontainer

I'm using SplitContainer (It's contain two panels) control under my MdifForm.I'm using following code to showing my exist forms under SplitContainer panel2

```
   With My_Form
        .MdiParent = Me
        SplitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(My_Form)
        .My_Form_Activated(Me, e)
        .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        .Show()
    End With
```

Docking fill command work properly at first displaying of the My_Form. But after mdiform resizing, my_form size doesn't change.
How can i fix this problem thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do not use FormWindowState.Maximised. instead use FormWindowState.Normal and then rely on DockStyle.Fill.